# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'postDirectOrder'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use this python package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pesapal in one of my projects.

But I noticed that for some weird reason the author stuffed all the logic in the [`__init__.py` file](https://github.com/kelonye/python-pesapal/blob/master/lib/__init__.py) which doesn't make sense to me, but hey..

So when I try to use the package I get the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'postDirectOrder
```

I'm on Python 2.7.7, I've tried `from pesapal import *` but no luck. I tried:

```
>>> from pesapal import PesaPal
>>> url = PesaPal.postDirectOrder(post_params, request_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method postDirectOrder() must be called with PesaPal instance as first argument (got dict inst
ance instead)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 0.3 release differs significantly from later code; it contains a *class* `PesaPal()` which takes `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` arguments:

```
pp = PesaPal(key, secret)
url = pp.postDirectOrder(post_params, request_data)
```

The project never correctly tagged the 0.3 release, but there is a [0.3 release commit](https://github.com/kelonye/python-pesapal/commit/1a7848fc84d7277e7faa9c697bd1455761ed996c#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e); you can [browse the source tree at that commit](https://github.com/kelonye/python-pesapal/tree/1a7848fc84d7277e7faa9c697bd1455761ed996c) to get an idea of what is expected.

The project README there includes an example:

> ```
> import pesapal, urllib2
>
> consumer_key ='consumer_key'
> consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret'
> testing = False
>
> ### make client
> client = pesapal.PesaPal(consumer_key, consumer_secret, testing)
>
> ### post a direct order
>
> request_data = {
>   'Amount': '',
>   'Description': '',
>   'Type': '',
>   'Reference': '',
>   'PhoneNumber': ''
> }
> post_params = {
>   'oauth_callback': 'www.example.com/post_payment_page'
> }
> request = client.postDirectOrder(post_params, request_data)
> # get url to display as an iframe
> print request.to_url()
> ```

Comment: If you install the code directly from github the example works as indicated in the current README. If you use pip you have to use the example above, very confused guy me thinks..

Comment: @jwesonga: I guess the project never released 0.4 and 0.5 on PyPI; they refactored the structure significantly. I guess it is still in the alpha release cycle, allowing the maintainers a lot of freedom in how to structure the package.